# Thread Safety of Reading a File

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, memory, io

So my end goal is to allow multiple threads to read the same file from start to finish. For example, if the file was 200 bytes:

```
Thread A  0-> 200 bytes
Thread B  0-> 200 bytes
Thread C  0-> 200 bytes
```

etc.

Basically have each thread read the entire file. The software is only reading that file, no writing.

so I open the file:

```
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_SYNC, 0);
```

and then in each thread simply loop the file. Because I only create one File Descriptor, are also create a create a clone of the file descriptor in each thread using dup

Here is a minimual example of a thread function:

```
void ThreadFunction(){
 int file_desc= dup(fd);
 uint32_t nReadBuffer[1000];
 int numBytes = -1;
 while (numBytes != 0) {
  numBytes = read(file_desc, &nReadBuffer, sizeof(nReadBuffer));
  //processing on the bytes goes here
 }
}
```

However, I'm not sure this is correctly looping through the entire file and each thread is instead somehow daisy chaining through the file.

Is this approach correct? I inherited this software for a project I am working on, the file descriptor gets used in an mmap call, so I am not entirely sure of O_RDWR or O_SYNC matter

Comment: Duplicated file descriptors share the same file position.

Comment: Each thread needs to open the file separately, you can't use `dup()` for this.

Comment: Depending on the size of the file, and depending on the number of threads, it might make sense to map the file into memory.

Comment: *Basically have each thread read the entire file. The software is only reading that file, no writing.* It'd be a *lot* more efficient to just read the file once and pass that buffer to each thread than it is to have each thread read the same data into separate buffers.

Comment: Why don't you just `mmap()` the file and let each thread read from the same mapping?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Reading the whole file into a buffer using the ordinary `read(...)` system call is fine if the file is small, but allocating that buffer could be a problem if the file is huge. That's where memory-mapping comes in. If you map a multi-gigabyte file into the process address space, your heap allocator doesn't need to know about it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I was just limiting my comment to the existing code already using `read()`.  `mmap()` works too, especially if the file is read many times, and has the advantage of much simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

As other folks have mentioned, it isn't possible to use a duplicated file descriptor here.  However, there is a thread-safe alternative, which is to use `pread`.  `pread` reads a file at an offset and doesn't change the implicit offset in the file description.

This does mean that you have to manually manage the offset in each thread, but that shouldn't be too much of a problem with your proposed function.